How to unsubscribe from Subject of System.Reactive
I am new to System.Reactive and having some confusion with the Subject and how to use it.
I have a basic implementation of a Subject here:
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    private readonly Subject<KeyValuePair<int, int>> _paginationSubject = new();
    private readonly List<IDisposable> _disposables = new();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _paginationSubject?.Dispose();
        foreach (var eachDisposable in _disposables)
        {
            eachDisposable?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void EmitPaginationChanges(KeyValuePair<int, int> pageAndSize)
    {
        _paginationSubject.OnNext(pageAndSize);
    }
     
    public void OnPaginationChanged(Action<KeyValuePair<int, int>> action)
    {
        _disposables.Add(_paginationSubject.Subscribe(action));
    }
}

Some class MessageCreator.cs(or a blazor page) is creating a message and emitting it through EmitPaginationChanges method.
Now a Receiver.cs class or blazoe page is subscribed to it through OnPaginationChanged method passing an Action. Now they can communicate between each other.
What I want to do is that as soon as the Receiver.cs object is no longer in use (destroyed) I want to unsubscribe from the Subject. So that the Action does not execute afterward and once the a new object of Receiver.cs is created it can subscribe to the Subject again.
